# How can I overwrite a text file through javascript in edge browser?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I tried to overwrite a text file which is in local path through javascript in edge(chromium).
But it doesn’t work.
I want to know that if Edge(Chromium version) supports to create a text file into local path.
If it possible, how can I do that?

Comment: no its not(shouldn't be) possible in any browser (excluding [beaker](https://beakerbrowser.com/))

Comment: You can't do that, you can only edit/overwrite a text file in the local if it is using node

Comment: Is it possible with node.js?

Comment: node.js isn’t run in a browser so: Not Applicable? Anyway, node.js runs in a context (via the installed NodeJS runtime executable) where filesystem access is _allowed_. So using NodeJS to modify a local file is about the same as getting a user to install/run any executable.

Answer (score 0):

We can't overwrite the local text file through JavaScript, it is not secure. If you want to modify the local text file, you could upload it through JavaScript, then, read the text content in the web page, after modifying it, download it to the local path.

Please check the following sample:

```
<input type="file" id="inputfile" /><br />
<input type="button" id="btn-dwn" value="Download" /><br />
<textarea id="text-val" rows="4"></textarea><br />

<script> 
    function newFile(data, fileName) {
        // download the content to a .txt file.
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            //IE11 support
            console.log("IE& Edge");
            // let blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/html" });// text/plain;charset=utf-8
            let blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {// other browsers
            console.log("Other browsers");
            var bl = new Blob([data], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(bl);
            a.download = fileName;
            a.hidden = true;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        }
    };

    //using FileReader to read the .txt file content
    document.getElementById('inputfile').addEventListener('change', function () { 
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('text-val').value = fr.result;
        } 
        fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
    });

    //call the newFile function to download text file.
    document.getElementById("btn-dwn").addEventListener('click', function () {
        newFile(document.getElementById("text-val").value, "test.txt");
    }); 
</script>
```